# Custom build system for sublime text 3

Tags: regex, g++, sublimetext3

I have a set of build scripts, used in build-system for sublime project, and I could not get navigation through errors to work.

Output looks something like this ( basically this is grep from g++ build output )

```
FileName.cxx:12:10: error: error message
```

As I understand from ["unofficial documentation"](http://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/build_systems.html#capturing-error-output-with-file-regex) first two patterns ( file and line number) are required to navigate to invalid code from build output. And I came with this field for build-system

```
"file_regex": "^(.*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? error:(.*)$"
```

Unfortunately it could not open file, it try to open directory where file resides.

Is something wrong with regex or I'm missing something in build-system configuration?

--- UPD
Thanks to Avinash Raj regex fixed, but the problem still exists.
I could see error message in status bar, but path could not be resolved, probably this is specific for windows, cause sublime try to open file "/c/dev/.../File.cxx:123"

Comment: change it like `^(.*?):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? error:(.*)$`

Comment: Thanks, that fixes a problem, unfortunately there is another one. Path is wrong, sublime tries to open "/c/dev/<rest_of_path>/file_name:<line>